# Overheated resistors

Tags: resistors, series

If resistors overheat and melt, like the one in series lights, will it cause fire?  I bought a LED Christmas lights. When I plugged in, the resistors started to melt and burn.  What happens if I keep them on?  Will it cause fire?

Comment: Yes! Unplug them immediately!

Comment: Resistors are not normally made of materials that can melt. The packaging around them might be able to. In any case, if something you plugged into the wall is melting, unplug it immediately and send it back.

Answer (score 2):

Resistors aren't made of material that would normally melt. The will generate a slight amount of heat but should never burn through the insulation material. The resistors are being overloaded so it may be the lights are for a 120V supply not 240V. If you have reassured that you are using the right supply there is probably a fault with the driver.